# How to filter certain field in jquery mobile filterable

Tags: jquery-mobile

i want to create dictionary app with jquery mobile and phonegap. but i have a problem with filter certain words in filterable widget

for example code, i used code example in filterable listview :

```
<form>
<input data-type="search" id="divOfPs-input">
</form>
   <div class="elements" data-filter="true" data-input="#divOfPs-input">
   <p><strong>These</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed            diam</p>
   <p><strong>tags</strong> nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam</p>
   <p><strong>Tags</strong> erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores </p>
    <p><strong>are</strong> et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est</p>
    <p><strong>Filterable</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  consetetur</p>
 </div>
```

my purpose is only filter words in 'strong' tags, not all words...how to do that? thanks for the answer..

Answer (score 0):

You do this using the **[filterCallback](http://api.jquerymobile.com/filterable/#option-filterCallback)** option of the filterable widget.  Basically, override the default filter to compare the search text against the `<strong>` text:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){    
    $(".elements").filterable('option', 'filterCallback', StrongSearch);
});


function StrongSearch( idx, searchValue ) {
    var ret = false;
    if (searchValue && searchValue.length > 0){ 
        var filttext = $(this).data("filtertext") || '';
        filttext = filttext.toLowerCase();
        var text = $(this).find("strong").text().toLowerCase();        
        if( text.indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase()) < 0 && filttext.indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase()) < 0){
            ret = true; //filter this one out
        }
    } 
    return ret;
}
```

On page create, set the filterable to use a filterCallback (StrongSearch in my example).  The callback passes the index of the item and the typed in search text. The `this` context of the callback is the element being checked (the `<p>` dom element in the example).

The line `var text = $(this).find("strong").text().toLowerCase();`  finds the text in the strong element while filttext checks to see if the data-filtertext attribute was used. Finally use the indexOf() javascript function to see if the search value is contained in either the strong text or the data-filtertext attribute.

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/hLrnptde/1/)**

For another example and more details, see this blog entry that demonstrates how to change the default filtering from contains the search text to starts with the search text (full disclosure, I wrote the entry):

**http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/07/30/starts-with-instead-of-contains-filter-text/**

Comment: wow done perfect...thanks for fast answer ezanker..i appreciate that

Comment: i am sorry ezanker, I still have question, I have tried your code, but I have a problem when using it in real filter words , for example I filtered word : “work” but have the return :
bookwork
breastworks 
brickwork
etc.
not the exact word : work, how to accomplish this?

Comment: ow sorry again..i just read your blog..and the answer is using != 0 not < 0 .. thanks

Comment: @GAJIkoegajikoe, the blog is doing something different (starts with instead of contains). Do you have it working now?

Comment: @GAJIkoegajikoe, great! Please consider accepting the answer so future searchers know that the question was answered.